# Is it more efficent to allocate a small object on the stack as apposed to creating it on the heap (once)?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, objectfactory

Currently with the library I have written, my small objects (which are not polymorphic) are allocated, within an object-pool, in a vector with `unique_ptr`'s. Now obviously I want to change this because there's obviously a lot of over-head in calling new so many times. I'm curious if it is more efficient to: cache the objects in the pool (store it in a vector, i.e. `vector<Object>`), or create the object when it is needed, via it's ID. And note that there is a lot of objects that are created.

What I mean is, should I be doing this:

Create the object when needed? (Note these objects are small, 64-128 bits, as all is contained is an ID and a reference/pointer to a parent object)

```
Object ObjectFactory::create()
{
    return Object(nextId(), getParent());
}

Object ObjectFactory::get(unsigned id)
{
    return Object(id, getParent());
}
```

or:

```
Object& ObjectFactory::create()
{
     // get the next id of the object
     unsigned id = nextId();

     // resize (if necessary)
     if(_objects.size() <= id)
     {
        _objects.resize(id + 1);
        _objects[id]._parent = getParent();
     }

     return _objects[id];
}

Object& ObjectFactory::get(unsigned id)
{ return _objects[id]; }
```

What I'm specifically concerned about is: would the re-creation of the `Object`'s cause much over-head?

Comment: There is one missing detail from this question: when you run the two versions, is the overhead of one too much?

Comment: Lets for a moment assume that heap is 100 times slower than stack. Would your application do it so often that it notices this difference? If not, is it not more important to have a clean, easy to use and maintain interface?

Comment: Storing objects in continuous memory (std::vector guarantees it) could bring you a huge speed improvement instead of store them in fragmented areas of memory.

Comment: Assuming a simple object which doesn't allocate any memory in its ctor or doing anything crazy in the dtor, then the stack allocation is faster since it involves adjusting the ESP reg on x86, the heap alloc can take a variable amount of time.

Comment: you can also use stack allocators with `std::vector` that allocate a static array on the stack and only go to the heap if your array has been filled.

Comment: I would worry about this `_objects.resize(id + 1);`. What is the type of `_objects`? Is resize going to move all the members and thus invalidate all th previous references you have returned!

Comment: @LokiAstari the type of ``_objects`` would be a vector, so it wouldn't invalidate the previous references I returned.

Comment: @miguel.martin: **Because it is a vector**. When you call resize() there is **definitely** a possibility of the internal data being moved. If this happens then all references (and iterator) you have previously returned are invalidated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LokiAstari is right, you clearly have a problem with your pointers on resize.

There's something I don't understand; you say you're using an object pool but that you have problems with too many new statements. If you're using an object pool, I would say it's precisely to avoid new statements, no?

Here are my suggestions, although I'm no expert and there might be better solutions involving the implementation of your own allocator typically (dark side of the force..). You could use a container like `std::deque`, which ensures the validity of pointers/references on resize.

You would begin with an initial resize of a lot of Objects (your pool), and you can either handle manually the subsequent resize when needed (extending the capacity with chunks of predefined size), or accept the new statements then if you know there shouldn't be a lot, and use the emplace_back method.

I also don't know if you're doing a lot of insertion/deletion of objects with your IDs. If so, you might consider using `std::unordered_map`.

Here is an example using `std::deque`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

#define POOL_RESERVE 1000


// Data storage for your object
struct MyObjectData
{
    double some_data;
};


// Container returned by the factory
struct MyObject 
{
    typedef MyObjectData data_type;

    unsigned   id; 
    data_type* data;

    MyObject(): id(0), data(0) {}
    MyObject( const unsigned& id_, data_type* data_ ): id(id_), data(data_) {}

    void set( const unsigned& id_, data_type* data_ )
        { id = id_; data = data_; }
};


// MyObject Pool
class MyObjectPool
{
public:

    typedef MyObjectData data_type;

    MyObjectPool(): count(0) { pool.resize(POOL_RESERVE); }

    void get( const unsigned& id, MyObject& obj )
        {
            // Check requested index
            if ( id >= count )
                obj.set( 0, 0 );
            else
                obj.set( id, &pool[id] );
        }

    void create( MyObject& obj )
        {
            // Create new data container if needed
            if ( count++ >= pool.size() ) pool.emplace_back();

            // Return next available object
            obj.set( count-1, &pool[count-1] );
        }

private:

    unsigned count;
    std::deque<data_type> pool;
};


// MyObject factory
class MyObjectFactory
{
    typedef MyObjectFactory self;
    static MyObject local;

    static MyObjectPool& get_instance()
        {
            static MyObjectPool pool; 
            return pool;
        }

public:

    static MyObject get( const unsigned& id )
        {
            self::get_instance().get(id,local);
            return local;
        }

    static MyObject create()
        {
            self::get_instance().create(local);
            return local;
        }
};

// Define static variable
MyObject MyObjectFactory::local = MyObject();


// Usage example
int main()
{
    MyObject a,b,c;

    a = MyObjectFactory::create();
    b = MyObjectFactory::create();
    c = MyObjectFactory::get(1);
}
```

Comment: Why use ``std::deque`` over ``std::vector``? I think I may use the 2nd option that I chose to use. BTW I don't think you needed to use singletons at all, just my opinion.

Comment: As I said, `std::vector` does not ensure the validity of pointers/reference after a `resize` or a `push_back`, this is why you need to use `std::deque`. Singleton is necessary in my opinion, since a pool should be accessible without passing explicitly a reference to the Factory (which is unclear and dangerous by the way); any function or method should be able to access the objects of the pool a priori, even though I don't know your program. What would happen if you factory accidentally got copied? Did you read the comment of @LokiAstari? Your second solution is _not_ valid.

Comment: @Sh3john, I read it.. Just didn't know it moved objects internally on resize and push_back.

Comment: And also... isn't that why you make the Factory non-copyable?

Comment: @miguel.martin Well that's a way to ensure it is not copied indeed. But think about the usage; how will you access the object #7 inside a function without passing a pointer/refereence to the factory as an input? Is it clean to do so? Furthermore to me, the Factory is not conceptually supposed to manage the pool of objects, so it make sense that the pool and the factory are separate objects -- but that's my own opinion.

Comment: @miguel.martin Actually the last point is another problem; it's not really a factory that we have here... Another important comment; if you use my suggestion, make sure that you do not set class members with it outside of the constructor, otherwise I think it's not guaranteed that the pool won't be deleted before the member, which could cause awkward sefaults..